# Update Ember model with Computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember Object and its Instantiation, on calling the "updateName" method periodically the property value updates, but is NOT reflected in the template via "model". Any guesses on what am I doing wrong?

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('application');
});

App.myData = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: 'luke',
    updateName: function(){
        this.set('name', Math.random(1,10)+'');
    },
    newName: function(){
        return this.get('name');
    }.property('name')
});

App.myDataObj = App.myData.create({});
setInterval( function(){ 
    App.myDataObj.updateName()
    console.log( App.myDataObj.get('newName') )
}, 5000 );

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return {
            name: App.myDataObj.get('newName')
        };
    }
});
```

Output: Luke
and thats it

Help Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**: this is not how things should be done in ember, for example you should use the template/route/controller tandem, and using `Ember.run.later` instead of `setInterval` etc. However, referencing the model in the template works, here is how you could achieve it:

#### Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Application</h2>
  {{model.newName}}
</script>
```

#### App:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    console.log('App ready');
  }
});

App.myData = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: 'luke',
  updateName: function(){
    this.set('name', Math.random(1,10)+'');
  },
  newName: function(){
    return this.get('name');
  }.property('name')
});

App.myDataObj = App.myData.create();

setInterval( function(){ 
  App.myDataObj.updateName();
  console.log( App.myDataObj.get('newName') );
}, 5000 );

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.myDataObj;
  }
});
```

#### Demo:

http://jsbin.com/ISoZIma/3/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your response. Like you said, I too believe that a "handlebars" template maping directly to the object is not a good idea, hence I used "model" to convey data. Problem is, model does NOT know when the computed property has updated. Or model is not updating itself.

Comment: @Amanpreet, I mean in general by "how things should be done in ember", referencing the model in the template works, see here: http://jsbin.com/ISoZIma/3/edit, I've updated my answer to use the model hook instead

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, basically my idea was to simulate "store" like object that would act like a container for data (Please assume that "Ember Data" is not an option). But what we have achieved here is simply redirecting the Object to template is it possible to extract just the property in the model and send it to the template?. Also would it be better to put this inside the controller rather than the model? in compliance to "how things should be done in ember"?